# ActiveRecord transaction e-mails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email, transactions

I'm running a lib at my rails 3 app that performs several inserts and updates on different models. It's like importing a CSV shopping list file which may be with errors that abort the import function.

So I have something like this:

```
begin
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @csv.each_with_index do |row, line_number|
      begin    
        shopping_list_importer.import(row)
      rescue Exception => e
        invalid_objects << {:message => e.message, :line_number => line_number+2}
      end
    end
    raise ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid if invalid_objects.present?
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
end
```

My problem is that when a new shopping list item is created it sends an e-mail for the user.
And when occurs some error the e-mail was already sended and the transaction doesn't block that. It's OK I understand why that occurs, and I should send the e-mails after the import, but my question is that is there a more simple way to do this and keep using transaction block?

Thanks in advance, 
Andre.

Answer (score 1):

What actually triggers email sends? If you keep that in a callback like `after_save` it will not send any emails if object wasn't properly saved. Like:

```
after_save :send_notification

def send_notification
  UserNotifier.something.deliver
end
```

Comment: mmm, Thanks for your reply but that's what I have now. But if any error occurs on the transaction the correct elements have already sended the emails.

Comment: Right. Sorry. I missed that. How about deferring email sending after the import is done? Setting up an attr_accessor :skip_notifications would do it. So during import assign that flag to the object and don't send email if it's present. Then after successful import cycle through imported objects and trigger `send_notification` method.

Comment: Yep I thought something like this... But this accessor will be needed after the import. In some cases I could have a very large shopping list. I thought that instead of using an accessor I should have a boolean "committed" column that gets me which lists were committed without failures and trigger the mailing method to the lists that were imported with success and e-mails wasn't sended yet. After send I update the committed value to true so they are marked as sended.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this: https://github.com/grosser/ar_after_transaction

It seems like it should solve this kind of problem elegantly.